# UIProgressview not updating its progress even when updating its progress second time on main thread

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, ios-simulator

Please don't flag it as duplicate as there are few questions similar to this, but mine issue is bit different.

I'm stuck at updating the UIProgressview progress 2nd time when I navigate to the specific UIViewController.

**Scenario:**  In my application **Home** screen I have different categories of animation Video list in collection view. On clicking the particular animation category it navigates to the **Animation Detail** (I have used navigation controller). On this screen I can also view multiple related animation videos and also have option to download the video. I have used UIProgress view to show the progress of the download.

At very 1st time when I navigate to the detailed screen and download the video, UIProgress view works fine and the corresponding download progress. On the same screen also I can download another related video with UIProgress view working properly.

**Now issue is when I navigate back to the Home and select different category of the animation video and then navigate again to the detailed screen. This time when hit the download video button video starts downloading, but this time the UIProgress view doesn't update its progress**

---

Note: I'm updating the UIProgress view's progress on the main thread.

---

**Following is my code:**

```
#pragma mark- NSURLSession Delegate method

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite{

double Progress = (double)totalBytesWritten / (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
NSLog(@"Progressview progress : %f",Progress);
if (totalBytesExpectedToWrite == NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown) {
    NSLog(@"Unknown transfer size");
}
else{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgress:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",Progress] waitUntilDone:NO];
}
}


-(void)updateProgress:(id)progress {

float currentProgress = [progress floatValue];
[downloadProgress setProgress:currentProgress animated:YES];
[self.downloadProgress setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

Please anyone help me. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the values of progress in updateProgress method using NSLog?

Comment: Add logging to updateProgress, values and insure downloadProgress is not nil. Even ask the control for its current value and log it.

Comment: Yes I have logged the values of the progress and they are not nil. They are between 0.1-1.0.

Comment: You are using navigation controller. Are you using pop/push view controllers to go back and forth.

Comment: @Ritu : Yes I'm using pop/push to go back and forth.

Comment: try [self.downloadProgress setProgress:currentProgress animated:YES]; instead of [downloadProgress setProgress:currentProgress animated:YES]; in updateProgress:

Comment: @Ritu: I tried it but, no change. It doesn't work.

Comment: setNeedsDisplay is not needed I think; where is declared the progressView? Are you sure it has not been deallocated?